# Javascript update value each 15 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

The page should show some value that come from some service

The value must be updated every 15 seconds. 
I know just one way to do it, use setInterval and using $.ajax call but some say what exist more then 5 ways to do it include not cross-browser. Could someone help me identify them ?

Thanks.

Comment: whatever the way that you gonna take, it will be the same idea behind.
1- Server code to serve the initial data
2- wait time before hitting the server-side service
3- fetch the data from the service
4- LOOP
so I think doing a setInterval is your friend here.

Comment: I can say there is zillion ways to do this ... and just matter, how hard way you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can change `document.location`, thus reloading the whole page
- You can put dynamic content in iframe and reload only this frame
- You can use WebSockets and let the server push the update

Answer (score 2):

You can also use alternatively, but it will refresh your whole page

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15">
```

With redirect to new page

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content=15";url=http://example.com/">
```

learn more [here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/metataglibraries/a/aa080300a.htm)

Answer (score 1):

If you want data inserted into a particular element, you don't need to call $.ajax because all you really want to do is pull data from a server-side script.  You can do this with $.load instead:

```
$(function() {
   setInterval(function() {
      $('.element').load('/location/to/script');
   },15000);
));
```

If you only require a value, then you can use $.ajax via JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `setInterval` and `$.ajax`

Comment: OP has already mentioned that.

Comment: @Sarfraz I felt it needed reiterating

Comment: I would use `setTimeout` and `$.ajax`.